# issue installing choroplethrzip

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, zipcode, choroplethr

I'm trying to install choroplethrZip as:
`devtools::install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.5.0')`

and received the message bellow. I can't also install dependent packages.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,

Kalbi

> Installing choroplethrZip
>
> Installation failed: formal argument "repos" matched by multiple actual arguments
>
> Installation failed: formal argument "repos" matched by multiple actual arguments
>
> "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.5/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" INSTALL "C:/Users/zongok/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpCA0aW5/devtoolsf184d3b50a8/arilamstein-choroplethrZip-3cbc9f3"

Comment: Can you please provide the results from running `sessionInfo()`?